# Cleanning Doctrine APC cache

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, apc

I added a field to an Entity.
Everything worked fine.

But, on production server, new field was not seen by doctrine.
The field really exists on the database but i can not filter on this field from doctrine query.

I looked in config.yml and i remove thoses lines:
metadata_cache_driver:apc
query_cache_driver:apc
result_cache_driver:pac

Everything works without thoses lines. So i think this APC cache kept an older configuration of entities.

Where is this cache and how can i clean it ?

Answer (score 1):

These are the symfony2 doctrine clear cache commands you can run from `app/console`:

```
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

Comment: I have done this but it did not change anything.
Where APC stores cache?

Comment: To clear the APC cache, you may have to write a service yourself, or import a bundle such as [ApcBundle](https://github.com/ornicar/ApcBundle) to help you achieve this

Comment: .. or reboot your server.

Comment: So this APC cache is store in RAM memory ? Not in file system ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this PHP script : https://github.com/asubit/script-for-delete-cache-symfony2

You just have to :

- **Dowload** the script [here](https://github.com/asubit/script-for-delete-cache-symfony2/archive/master.zip)
- **Put your IP address** in the script (for secure the execution in production environnement)
- **Change the secret token** in the script (`123456` for exemple...)
- **Upload the script** on your `web` directory of your production environnement
- **And just access the script** (`www.your-domain.com/web/delete-cache.php?token=123456`).

It will clear the TWIG cache, the Symfony `app/cache` of your active environnement and the APC cache.

Hope this help.